# Failed to resolve component?

Tags: vuejs3

Can someone help me how fix this warning?

When I load the page I get this warning in console:

[image]

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <Navbar />
  <Doodle />

  <div class="container text-light cat-head">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>




<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import Doodle from "@/components/Doodle";

export default {
  components: { Navbar, Doodle },
};

</script>
```